How to use mui styled on react components and to change style inside the wrapped component?
In the code below: How can I change the border-bottom property inside Header inside SpecialTabs ith styled?
Thanks!!
const SpecialTabs = () => {
  const Header = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
`;
  return (
    <Header>
      <Tabs>
        ...
      </Tabs>
    </Header>
  )
}

const StyledTabs = styled(SpecialTabs)(() => ({
  " & .Mui-disabled": {
    padding: 0,
  },
}));

const App = () => {
  return (
    <StyledTabs>
      ...
    </StyledTabs>
  )
}

What I tried (but doesnt work):
const StyledTabs = styled(SpecialTabs)(() => ({
  " & .Mui-disabled": {
    padding: 0,
  },
  borderBottom: "none"
}));


Can you rephrase your question to be more understandable? What are you trying to achieve? Your question doesn't really seem comprehensible enough.

Im not sure how to phrase it better than inside the post with the code

One way is to conditionally render border using prop, like this:
const Header = styled('div')(({ removeBorder }) => ({   
  borderBottom: removeBorder ? 'none' : '1px solid red', 
})); 

than use Header like this
<Header removeBorder={true}>
and in the App it will look like this
<StyledTabs removeBorder> ... </StyledTabs>
here's fiddle so you can check it out -> FIDDLE
Another way could be to pass className to Header, but haven't test this so I can't confirm
<Header className="header"> and target it in StyledTabs
'& .header': { border: none }

Thank you a lot! I tried the second solution without passing the removeBorder prop as that would be more beneficial and its not working unfortunately. With the first solution, for some reason the border is always removed, whether removeBorder is true,false or undefined

I updated fiddle, using return <StyledTabs removeBorder={false} />; seems to be working fine, you can set default value const SpecialTabs = ({ children, removeBorder = false }) => { ... }  so it always shows unless you set it to true in StyledTabs, or you can default it to true.
This works in fiddle, maybe you missed something

Thanks, I actually did miss something :)
